# WFS-T app error: No such feature type

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs

I'm trying to develop a WFS-T on a web page using the Boundless WebAppBuilder SDK with QGIS.  I have an HTML page referencing a WFS coming from GeoServer with an MSSQL source.  When I try to draw a new feature, I get an error from Firebug saying:

```
"No such feature type http://(my ip):(port)/geoserver/DRTEST:polygontest"
```

This is the section of my JavaScript with the parameters:

```
var lyr_polygontest = new ol.layer.Vector({
     opacity: 1.0,
     source: wfsSource_polygontest,  
     style: style_polygontest,
     selectedStyle: selectionStyle_polygontest,
     title: "polygontest",
     id: "polygontest20161121124618872",
     wfsInfo: {
         featureNS: 'http://(ip:port)/geoserver/DRTEST', //http://(ip:port)/geoserver/DRTEST
         typeName: 'DRTEST:polygontest',
         featureType: 'polygontest',
         geometryType: 'Polygon',
         geometryName: 'the_geom',
         url: 'http://(my ip):(port)/geoserver/DRTEST/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=text/javascript'
    },
    isWFST:true,
    filters: [],
    timeInfo: null,
    isSelectable: true,
    popupInfo: "<table class='popup-table'><tr><th>Attribute</th><th>Value</th><tr><td>id</td><td style='text-align:right'>[id]</td></tr></table>"
});
```

Any suggestions on what parameters need to be changed?  I'm still trying to figure out if the problem is if GeoServer is only looking for the namespace instead of an actual HTTP request.

Comment: what actual WFS GetFeature request is made?

Comment: http://(ip:port)/geoserver/DRTEST/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=text/javascript

Comment: What is the URI of the workspace your store is in?  That is what you should use for the namespace.

Comment: The WFS GetFeature request is missing the typename parameter, the request should be like one of the below URLs: `http://(ip:port)/geoserver/DRTEST/ows?service=WFS&version=1.‌​0.0&request=GetFeatu‌​re&outputFormat=text‌​/javascript&typename=polygontest&` or `http://(ip:port)/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.‌​0.0&request=GetFeatu‌​re&outputFormat=text‌​/javascript&typename=DRTEST:polygontest&`

Comment: `I'm still trying to figure out if the problem is if GeoServer is only looking for the namespace instead of an actual HTTP request` GeoServer only works against HTTP requests sent, in this case requests generated by your JavaScript code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try adding the typename parameter first thing tomorrow and let you know what happens

Comment: It turns out that I had to leave the url just at the ows argument after the workspace name and I had to use the GML link in the layer preview for geoserver to have the right parameters.  Also, make sure you have the right geometry column name; this app assumes "the_geom" as the geometry column name, which wasn't the case in my MSSQL database (I believe that's the default for PostGIS data).

Comment: I'm having the same issue , could anyone knows the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I had to leave the url just at the ows argument after the workspace name and I had to use the GML link in the layer preview for geoserver to have the right parameters. Also, make sure you have the right geometry column name; the Boundless python program WebAppBuilder assumes "the_geom" as the geometry column name, which wasn't the case in my MSSQL database (I believe that's the default for PostGIS data).

```
var lyr_polygontest = new ol.layer.Vector({
                        opacity: 1.0,
                        source: wfsSource_polygontest,  
                        style: style_polygontest,
                        selectedStyle: selectionStyle_polygontest,
                        title: "polygontest",
                        id: "polygontest20161208112642749",
                        wfsInfo: {featureNS: 'http://geoserver.org/DRTEST',
                featureType: 'polygontest',
                typeName: 'DRTEST:polygontest',
                geometryType: 'Polygon',
                geometryName: 'ogr_geometry',//'the_geom',
                url: 'http://(my ip:port)/geoserver/DRTEST/ows'
              },
              isWFST:true,
                        filters: [],
                        timeInfo: null,
                        isSelectable: true,
                        popupInfo: "<table class='popup-table'><tr><th>Attribute</th><th>Value</th><tr><td>ogr_fid</td><td style='text-align:right'>[ogr_fid]</td></tr><tr><td>id</td><td style='text-align:right'>[id]</td></tr></table>"
                    });
```